# MySQL & Python: How to map the table data?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, cursor

I have the following database structure:

```
TABLE 'images' (id,name,format)
TABLE 'objects'(id,title)
TABLE 'images_objects'(id,image_id,object_id)
```

Where `image_id` and `object_id` are the foreign keys to `images_objects` table respectively. So I filled the first two tables, now I want to populate the third table with id pairs. Which SQL QUERY should I construct?

Comment: is id field in images_objects an identity field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a catersian product of the two tables and populate the mapping table.

Eg:

```
   insert 
     into images_objects
          (image_id
          ,object_id
          )
   select i.id as image_id
          ,o.id as object_id
     from images i
     join objects o 
       on 1=1
```

Comment: yes because cartesian product will map each and every combination (n*n)

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . This would normally be written using `CROSS JOIN`.